# Query optimization in oracle (check for rows with a specific fk value)

Tags: oracle

I have a table (a big one) which has (i'm guessing), more than 200k rows. The thing is, in this table, there's a fk to another table (which i'm trying to delete a record), but when it check for constraints, it's really slow. I came with this query:

```
SELECT ID_PRAZO_ENTRG FROM PRAZO_ENTRG WHERE ID_TIPO_SERV = :idTipoServ AND ROWNUM <= 3
```

It's really fast if there are rows with the value i've passed in the parameter. But if there's not, it takes a really long time to finish the query. How can i achieve the same result with a faster query?

Comment: can you post the execution plan?

Comment: You must include more information. With any performance related question, always post the details about the slow query, objects involved, indexes, number of rows in the table, and of course, tje execution plan.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have no index for the foreign key column. Try to

```
CREATE INDEX PRAZO_ENTRG_TIPO_SERV_I ON PRAZO_ENTRG(TIPO_SERV);
```